# Compare the system date with date from a text file

Tags: string, shell, date, unix-timestamp

I get the date that's inside a text file and assigned it to a variable.  When I grep the date from the file, I get this,

```
Not After : Jul 28 14:09:57 2017 GMT
```

So I only crop out the date, with this command

```
echo $dateFile | cut -d ':' -f 2,4
```

The result would be

```
Jul 28 14:57 2017 GMT
```

How do I convert this date to the number of seconds, so I can compare it to the system date?  If it is over 2 days old.

I have this code but it doesn't work.  I'm getting an error message when I ran it.  I think its because $dateFile is a text file and it doesn't know how to convert it.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

$dateFile=grep "After :" myfile.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2,4

AGE_OF_MONTH="172800" # 172800 seconds  = 2 Days
NOW=$( date +%s )
NEW_DATE=$(( NOW - AGE_OF_MONTH ))

if [ $( stat -c %Y "$dateFile" ) -lt ${NEW_DATE} ]; then
   echo Date Less then 2 days
else
   echo Date Greater then 2 days
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors in your script.  Please try the below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# capture the seconds since epoch minus 2 days
NOW=`expr $(date '+%s') - 172800`  

# read every line in the file myfile.txt
while read -r line;
do
  # remove the unwanted words and leave only the date info
  s=`echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 2,4`
  # parse the string s into a date and capture the number of seconds since epoch
  date=$(date -d "$s" '+%s')

  # compare and print output
  if [ $date -lt $NOW ]; then
    echo "Date Less then 2 days, s=$s, date=$date, now=$NOW"
  else
    echo "Date Greater then 2 days, s=$s, date=$date, now=$NOW"
  fi
done < myfile.txt
```

However this will not work:
`$dateFile=grep "After :" myfile.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2,4`. In the shell you cannot prefix a variable name with `$` since the shell will try to evaluate the result as a variable and also in order to execute a command and assign it to a variable you need to surround it in `$(....)` or with backticks.

Example with variable and piping it to the while:

```
#!/bin/sh

dateFile=`grep "After :" my.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2,4`

# capture the seconds since epoch minus 2 days
NOW=`expr $(date '+%s') - 172800`

echo "$dateFile" | while read -r line;
do
  # parse the string s into a date and capture the number of seconds since epoch
  date=$(date -d "$line" '+%s')

  # compare and print output
  if [ $date -lt $NOW ]; then
    echo "Date Less then 2 days, s=$line, date=$date, now=$NOW"
  else
    echo "Date Greater then 2 days, s=$line, date=$date, now=$NOW"
  fi
done
```

Example piping the grep and the while:

```
#!/bin/sh

# capture the seconds since epoch minus 2 days
NOW=`expr $(date '+%s') - 172800`

grep "After :" myFile.txt | cut -d ':' -f 2,4 | while read -r line;
do
  # parse the string s into a date and capture the number of seconds since epoch
  date=$(date -d "$line" '+%s')

  # compare and print output
  if [ $date -lt $NOW ]; then
    echo "Date Less then 2 days, s=$line, date=$date, now=$NOW"
  else
    echo "Date Greater then 2 days, s=$line, date=$date, now=$NOW"
  fi
done
```

Hope this clarifies your questions.

Comment: Your code works perfectly.  Thank you.  Just wondering why you would need a loop to read every line in the file cause the command grep will automatically get the info you need???

Comment: I've edited my answer in order to respond to your question. Please select it as the correct answer if your are satisfied with it.